# iOS: How to create the failed login animation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm trying to create a function, that when the user failed to insert the pass or the email in the login view, the screen will shake, someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: add the code ..

Comment: Please add your code, not a screenshot, but by pasting in to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can shake any view with this function

```
 public func shakeView() {

    let shake: CAKeyframeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    shake.values = [NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0)), NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5.0, 0.0, 0.0))]
    shake.autoreverses = true
    shake.repeatCount = 2.0
    shake.duration = 0.07

    self.layer.add(shake, forKey:"shake")
}
```

to shake view you can either create extension or do little make little changes in below function to shake any view.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply shake animation via `CABasicAnimation`.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       shakeAnimation()
    }

    func shakeAnimation() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.3
        animation.repeatCount = 10
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x - 10, y:  self.view.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x + 10, y:  self.view.center.y))
        self.view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a view for it some time ago. Place everything inside it in interface builder, link the view as IBOutlet and call:

```
shakeItView.shake(completion: { _ in })
```

Code for my component:

```
public final class ShakeItView: UIView {

    public func shake(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.07 - TimeInterval(count) * 0.01, delay: 0.01, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [unowned self] in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: CGFloat(10 * self.direction), y: 0)
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            if self.count >= 4 {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                self.resetValues()
                completion(true)
            } else {
                self.count += 1
                self.direction *= -1
                self.shake(completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }

    private var direction: Int = 1
    private var count: Int = 0

    private func resetValues() {
        direction = 1
        count = 0
    }

}
```